# JRE rt.jar behaving differently as compared to JDK rt.jar

Tags: java, jar

Some days back I ran into a weird issue where I was using JAXB to unmarshal an XML file. So the code I wrote is below.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XxspPoInHeaderCollection.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller(); //step1
XxspPoInHeaderCollection poInHeaderCollection = (XxspPoInHeaderCollection) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file));
```

So this was a working code which I then checked in **SVN**. Now from some other system I picked up the same code, but on that system the code was unable to find any XML tags while unmarshalling. After hours of debugging, I found one minor difference in both the environments. At above step1, the working system was picking the `rt.jar` from **JDK_HOME/jre/lib** and the non-working was picking it from **JRE_HOME/lib**. So the **jre**'s `rt.jar` was causing the issue.
My project is a the runnable jar. So on non-working system, when I was running it using `java -jar jarName.jar` from any directory, it was causing the issue. So I tried running the jar file from the **JDK_HOME/bin**(as below) and boom...everything ran fine.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin>java -jar "C:\Users\puspender.tanwar\project\850\Adapter-0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Now i have few questions in mind:
1. why this issue is coming up? Why rt.jar is different in JRE and JDK
2. My runnable jar file has dependency on some files which I cannot put inside the jar. And while running it using the above approach, I need to keep them under **JDK_HOME/bin**. Is there any good approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was your difference in observed behavior, but one thing comes to my mind is...

JDK bundles a (defined) version of JAXB, while JRE doesn't. This could result in JAXB not being available on the "JRE-only computer". Or using a different version from classpath.

Comment: If that is the case, isn't it a bad approach? As for using any application which uses JAXB, even a non-programmer personal will be forced to download and configure the JDK.